# dracut: use only specified configuration file

Tags: initramfs, dracut

Is it possible to tell **dracut** do not use configuration files in `/etc/dracut.conf.d/` and `/usr/lib/dracut/dracut.conf.d` during **initramfs** creating?

I move configuration files to temporary directory before creation of **initramfs** for another system, and put it back after creation. I haven't seen any option in `man` pages about **dracut**. Maybe I'm not so careful.

Comment: You could use mount tricks to hide the files, and a mount name-space, to make it visible to only the relevant processes.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks for suggestion. I'll try this solution later and write about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running dracut manually, then you can run `dracut --conf CONFFILE --confdir CONFDIR`

See [man 8 dracut](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dracut)

However, dracut will mostly be run from a package manager's on kernel install hooks. E.g. on RHEL7, it's run from `/usr/lib/kernel/install.d/50-dracut.install`. And if this is the case, the direct answer to your question is no.

What you can do is create a conf file name `/etc/dracut.conf.d/99_custom.conf` and in that config file override any settings from other config files, with options such as `dracutmodules`, `omit_dracutmodules`, etc.

Comment: An approach with `/etc/dracut.conf.d/99_custom.conf` sounds like good. It seems is what I want! Thanks!